# Getting single user from Firebase with Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm learning Angular since a month, and to practice it I decided to make a website.
I configured a database with Firebase where I save the data of my users and know I want to give the possibility to a user to edit his data.

In order to be more precise, I use the authentication of Firebase to create the account, and at this moment I save the UID associated to this account to set it in the Realtime Database, with more informations about the user that he provides just after the registration.

To do this, I set the uid provided by Firebase in the database, and then I wanna give access to the current user to the data where the same uid is saved, so he can edit them.

However, I did not succeed to get the data corresponding to a specific user. Here's the code I tried :

```
ngOnInit() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
      (user) => {
        if (user) {
          console.log(user.uid);
          this.userService.getUserFromServer();
          this.prenom = this.userService.getUserbyKey(user.uid).prenom;
          this.nom = this.userService.getUserbyKey(user.uid).nom;
          this.pseudo = this.userService.getUserbyKey(user.uid).pseudo;
          this.ville = this.userService.getUserbyKey(user.uid).ville;
          this.enfants = this.userService.getUserbyKey(user.uid).enfants;
          this.hobbies = this.userService.getUserbyKey(user.uid).hobbies;
          this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({ edit: [], })
        } else { console.log('No user connected') }
      }
    );
  }
```

Based on this model : (the key is the user.uid generated when the user created his account)

```
    constructor(
        public key: string,
        public prenom: string,
        public nom: string,
        public pseudo: string,
        public ville: string,
        public enfants: string,
        public hobbies?: string[]
    ) { }
```

Here's the "getUserbyKey" method :

```
getUserbyKey(key: string) {
        const singleUser = this.users.find(
            (s) => {
                return s.key === key;
            }
        );
        return singleUser;
    }
```

But when I try to access to the page linked to this ngOnInit(), I always get this error :

> ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.userService.getUserbyId(...) is undefined
>
> ngOnInit/<@http://localhost:4200/main.js:1296:48

I'm stuck with this problem, so if someone can give me a clue, it will be very helpful !

Comment: you have not defined this function in your service file 
getUserbyId

Comment: Actually it's defined, I just forgot to actualize restart the server, but I changed the name of the function I've now : ERROR TypeError: "this.userService.getUserbyKey(...) is undefined".
But it's defined, so I don't understand this error